# addEventListener("click") getting called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 different buttons that I want a user to be able to type a signature. When I just click 1 of them, it works fine. But when I click on the next button without a page refresh, it runs the process for the second button, but then runs the process for the first option again.

Can anyone help me find out what I am doing wrong so that only 1 button will be processed when it is clicked on?

```
$('#button1').click(function (event) {
var id = "button1",
    sigSign = $(this);
signatureSignage(id, sigSign);
});

$('#button2').click(function (event) {
var id = "button2",
    sigSign = $(this);
signatureSignage(id, sigSign);
});


function signatureSignage(id, sigSign) {
$("#sigPadContainer").fadeIn();
$('#closeSigPad').click(function (event) {
    $("#sigPadContainer").fadeOut();
});

var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad"),
    clearButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=clear]"),
    saveButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=save]"),
    canvas = wrapper.querySelector("canvas"),
    signaturePad;

function resizeCanvas() {
    var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
    canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
resizeCanvas();

signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

clearButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    signaturePad.clear();
});
saveButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) { /* alert you forgot to sign */ } else { /* This get's run twice */ }
});
}
```

Comment: You are adding event listeners, inside a function which it itself an event listener. This is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: what do you recommend @NiettheDarkAbsol ?

Comment: You should just set the listeners for `clearButton` and `saveButton` at the same time you set the listeners for `button1` and `button2` at the top of the script

Comment: @PatrickGunderson Then the information i sent through `signatureSignage` causes stuff I want to do through the `saveButton` event listener stop working :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NiettheDarkAbsol put me in the right direction for this. Here is my new code incase anyone is interested.

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad"),
clearButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=clear]"),
saveButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=save]"),
id, signaturePad;

/* Signature Sign */
$('.sigSign').click(function(event) {
    id = $(this).attr("name");

         if(id == "sig1") { signatureSignage(id); }
    else if(id == "sig2") { signatureSignage(id); }

});

$('#sig1').click(function(event) {
    id = "sig1";
    signatureSignage(id);
});

$('#sig2').click(function(event) {
    id = "sig2";
    signatureSignage(id);
});


$('#closeSigPad').click(function(event) { $("#sigPadContainer").fadeOut(); });
clearButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) { signaturePad.clear(); });
saveButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) { /* Do the save thing */ });

function signatureSignage(id)
{
    $("#sigPadContainer").fadeIn();
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad"), canvas = wrapper.querySelector("canvas");

    function resizeCanvas() {
        var ratio =  window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
        canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
        canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
        canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
    }

    window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
    resizeCanvas();

    signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
}
```